# Webpack sass loader with sourcemaps and url statements

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack, sass-loader

I have read that in order to have source maps, I have to use absolute urls in the `url('')` statement.
I did it this way :

```sass
body
    background-image: url('/elements/assets/tmp_background.jpg')
```

It works when I remove the sourceMap option from the css loader, it does not if I activate it.

I think I might have failed somewhere on the absolute path point, do you have any ideas?

Here is my config file :

```javascript
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'elements/main.js'),
  ],
  output: {
    path: 'dist',
    publicPath: '/',  // Prefix for all the statics urls
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname),
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015',
      },
      { test: /\.css$/,  loaders: ['style', 'css'] },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap'] },
      { test: /\.sass$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap&indentedSyntax=true'] },
      { test: /\.jade$/, loaders: ['ngtemplate', 'html', 'jade-html'] },
      { test: /\.(png|gif|jp(e)?g)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2))(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=50000' },
    ],
  },
};
```

On a more general idea, I could not find a working example of what I'm trying to do. I would be very interested if you can redirect me to that.

Answer (score 1):

The `publicPath` can be used to fix this, until a cleaner solution appears.

See https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/29

Comment: I was unable to get this working.  Can you give me an example?  I have in my webpack.config.js: `module.export = {...output: { publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/', ...}` but I am still not getting images to load unless I remove the ?sourceMap from the loader string.

Comment: This solution actually only works in dev mode, since `http://localhost:3000/` is not the URL of the prod. I ended up disabling CSS source maps in production...

Comment: I'm running in dev mode and it doesn't work for me at all there.  I wouldn't need source maps in production either, so I don't have those enabled, so everything works fine there.

I actually ended up just using the extract-text-plugin, and it's working for me now.